# OpenNLP FeatureGenerator with real number values

Tags: java, opennlp, named-entity-recognition, word-embedding

I'm trying to create a custom Word Embedding feature generator to use on the OpenNLP TokenNameFinder model. However, if I understand it correctly, the custom features need to implement AdaptiveFeatureGenerator class, and the signature to generate the features is:

```
public void createFeatures(List<String> feats, String[] tokens, int index, String[] preds)
```

which basically restricts the features to be categorical (since the features are list of Strings)... It would be great if someone could provide me some insights on whether numerical features are possible to create in OpenNLP, and if there is any work-around for this. Thank you so much for your time!